# Append data from url to div onclick jquery

Tags: jquery, load, append

when a link is clicked on my site i'm trying to append data from a given url to a specified div.

I thought this would work

```
onclick='$("#itemid_<?=$id?>").load("http://domain.com/file.php?q=<?=$term?>");'
```

but it doesn't seem to be working

if anyone could help that would be great

thanks

Comment: it looks fine... is there any script error in the page

Comment: is http://domain.com the same origin?

Comment: yes it is, its loading a local file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try something like this, construct the `url` in `href` and use a function with div id and url (`this.href`), like :

```
<a href="http://domain.com/file.php?q=<?=$term?>" onclick="return loadPage('#itemid_<?=$id?>', this.href);">Link Text</a>
```

Keep this function in your `head` section

```
function loadPage(id, url)
{
    $(id).load(url);
    return false;
}
```

By default, when you click a link, browser will load that page from the server, so, if you want to prevent this behaviour then you should use JavaScript code and in this case I've used `return false` to stop the browser from loading a page but there are other alternatives available, like `event.preventDefault`.

Also, check [jQuery load](http://api.jquery.com/load/), there are other ways to to this same thing, like

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.someLinks').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#someDiv').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });
});
```

You didn't provide more information but there must be a way to use this approach and it's better to use this way instead of `inline event` handling.